# Currency formatting using Western digits

Tags: java, android, locale, currency

I need to be able to display currency amounts where the currency is of the user's preferred locale, but using only Western digits. For example, if the user's chosen locale for the currency is `ar_AE` (for the United Arab Emirates) then the amount should be displayed as

```
AED 1,234.56
```

or something similar, using the correct currency name and number of decimal places, but using Western digits.

At the moment, I'm using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)` which formats the text using Arabic glyphs.

What options do I have? I'm looking for a general solution which won't require me to have specific knowledge of any given currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a currency formatter with number formatting according to the English locale, but using the default locale's currency, I would try something like this:

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    nf.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `DecimalFormat` like this:

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat( "AED #0.00" , new DecimalFormatSymbols( Locale.ENGLISH)).format( 1.23 ));
```

Edit: to use the locale for currency too, try this:

```
System.out.println(Currency.getInstance( Locale.GERMANY ).getCurrencyCode() + " " + 
    new DecimalFormat( "#0.00" , new DecimalFormatSymbols( Locale.GERMANY )).format( 1.23 ));
```

Prints: `EUR 1,23`

Comment: I'm really looking for a general solution which won't require me to have specific knowledge of any given currency.